# I am having trouble receiving bluetooth messages

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to receive bluetooth messages from a bluetooth board, the problem is that I am only getting certain messages received.. namely "AT+QSPPSEND=2,126".

If I try using a bluetooth terminal app, I receive the correct messages every 5 seconds where as on this I get that message about every minute or so.

Where have I gone wrong, does that runnable code not recieve the exact messages sent by the board?

```
 void beginListenForData() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[10024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        myLabel.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: is your problem with a specific device ? i didn't understand your problem can you explain it more ?

Comment: I can read the messages from other "bluetooth terminal apps" fine.. so I don't know really, it seems like that code isn't capturing the input stream messages and outputting them onto the text view.

Comment: I have checked that on another bluetooth terminal app that I receive that same message(AT+QSPPSEND=2,126) every minute or so the same, so why is it not showing these other messages?

Comment: you must know that the max size of data in BLE is 512bytes. are your data less than that ?

Comment: Yes, it's less than that, is it to do with this? byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {

Comment: what are the android OS in your devices ? both of them ?

Comment: Well.. one is just a standard serial bluetooth board, not an android device, that is the one sending messages..

Comment: try to use a Lollipop device. 5.1 or over will be good bea-cause it's much more stable than kitkat

Comment: Tried it.. no luck :(

Comment: is it a classic bluetooth or BLE ??

Comment: Classic I believe, I just have a massive feeling its the code is wrong as I am recieving one of the normal messages but not the rest like on terminals.

Comment: Could it be a problem with my go message? the board only sending the standard message and my go command is not good to request all the other data?

Comment: i really don't have a big idea on classic bluetooth

Comment: It's ok, I fixed it.. really strange but it didn't like putting any of them strings into the textview, I used a toast and the messages appeared fine, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I fixed it.. really strange but it didn't like putting any of them strings into the textview, I used a toast and the messages appeared fine, thanks for your help